# Creating script to cp directory multiple times

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a directory called `DS1`. I am trying to copy it 4 times so I also have `DS2`, `DS3`, `DS4` and `DS5`.

I am able to use the following command from the terminal and it works:

```
for i in {2..5}; do cp -r /home/test/DS1 "DS$i"; done
```

However, when I enter it into a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in {2..5}; do cp -r /home/test/DS1 "DS$i"; done
```

It creates one directory named `DS{2..5}` instead of the directories with increments between 2 and 5. Not understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{2..5}` is [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion). Brace expansion is not [standardized by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). Some, but not all, of the widely used [Bourne-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell#Relationship_to_other_shells) shells support it.

The shell you interact with in a terminal on Ubuntu is `bash`, unless you're deliberately using a different one. `bash` supports brace expansion. **But the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) on your script is for `sh`, which [on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) is a [symlink](https://foldoc.org/symlink) to `dash`**. `dash` does not support brace expansion.

So you can either:

1. Make your script a `bash` script (or a script for some other shell that supports brace expansion, such as `zsh` or `ksh`).
2. Replace brace expansion in your script with something that works in `dash`.

---

If you want to make your script a `bash` script, replace

```sh
#!/bin/sh
```

with:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
```

Then when run like `./scriptname` it will be run in `bash`. If you're running your script by writing `sh scriptname` then you must use `bash scriptname` instead.

---

If you want to eliminate brace expansion, there are a few alternatives.  I suggest `seq` with [command substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03), which is probably the most common alternative to brace expansion, is easy to write, and is likely to be understood by other human readers.

In place of `{2..5}`, you can write `$(seq 2 5)`. Since it is not quoted--that is, since it is `$(` `)` and not `"$(` `)"`--[field splitting](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) (which in `bash` is called [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting)) is performed on the result. So long as you have not set the [`IFS` shell variable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS), which controls field splitting, to a value that contains any digit or that does not contain a newline, this will do what you want.

([Globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Unix-like)--also called [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion), also called [pathname expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06)--is also performed on the result of unquoted command substitution, but the output of `seq` will not contain the [globbing characters](https://foldoc.org/glob) `?`, `*`, or `[`, so that has no effect in this case.)

Note that `seq` is [not standardized](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298199/portable-posix-shell-alternative-to-gnu-seq1) by POSIX. This will work on just about any GNU/Linux system and some other Unix-like operating systems, but some Unix-like OSes don't have `seq` installed by default (they usually have `jot` instead) so it is not guaranteed to work on all Unix-like operating systems.

Comment: Wow.  I knew I had to be doing something wrong.  Glad I did because now I learned something new.  I really appreciate the help.  The solution worked; just tested it.  Thanks @Eliah-Kagan

Answer (score 5):

When you run the script in your terminal, the shell that you are using is most likely Bash. Bash supports [brace expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace), so `{2..5}` gets expanded to the sequence `2 3 4 5` and your script works as you expect it to work.

When you add the same scipt to a file, however, it does not work. This is due to the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) that you are using (`#!/bin/sh`), which tells your script to run in the sh shell, which is POSIX-compliant and does not support braces expansion.

So you have two options:

1. Change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` or another shell that supports brace expansion.

or

2. Use `#!/bin/sh` and replace `{2..5}` by `$(seq 2 5)`.

Also take a look at this interesting Stack Overflow question about the [differences between sh and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @user3140225 you and Eliah were absolutely correct.  I really appreciate the help!